# How to abort running Groovy script in Hybris?

Tags: groovy, cron, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created the groovy script to reprocess a failed process and save in backoffice.

[image]
There is requirement where I have to manually abort groovy script. Thus anyone can suggest the way if we can abort Groovy script like Cronjob?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all cronjobs in SAP Commerce start in a dedicated thread.
Thus you should be able to identify the thread your groovy script is running in by going to the hAC and executing a thread dump (Monitoring -> Thread Dump). In that thread dump find the thread and kill it with below groovy code from the Scripting Languages View.

I've used this approach a couple times, but only in very rare occasions when really nothing else helped.

```
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
threads.each {
  if(it.name.startsWith("YOURCRONJOBNAME")){
    it.interrupt()
    print "KILLED\t"
  } else{
    print "\t"
  }
  println "${it.name}"
}
```

You should always make sure to implement the `Abortable` contract (by overriding `isAbortable()`) when implementing custom cronjobs, then you'll be able to stop them from within the backoffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement abortable cronjobs. Groovy scripts might not be abortable at all (except by killing the thread as suggested in the answer above).

For abortable cronjobs see here:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8be670d686691014bdbfac79c33da20e.html